# Uniqueness in AWS dynamoDB items based on can be empty fields

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda

I am using AWS lambda(python) and dynamodb to add items to dynamodb.

My item has structure like
{id,email,mobile}

I need to add items to db based on the fact that no email or mobile number is duplicated in new item.

Items may or maynot have email or mobile.

How to achieve this?

**For example**

I now have an item in db

{1,email@mail.com,123456789}

I can add

- {2,mail@gmail.com}
- {3,72562626262}
- {4,jk@yahoo.com,919191919191}

But not

- {5,email@mail.com}
- {6,email@mail.com,0909090990}
- {7,123456789}

Answer (score 0):

Dynamodb can force uniqueness only for hash-range table keys (not for global secondary index keys)

so in your case (and the scenario described above), to only way you can avoid duplicates for email or mobile is in application level, by making email and mobile global secondary hash keys (and query for item before update).

if you use multithreading then use locks on query/update.